# Clear Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

Is it possible to clear `DataAnnotations` in derived classes ?

```
public class User
{
   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (UserMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "BIRTHDATE_REQUIRED")]
    public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Derived Class

```
public class UserModel : User
{
   //i dont want data annotations to be used here
   [Clear] - something like this
   public override DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes, its possible by setting Inherited as false. Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can clear the annotations for derived class as specified below by settting Inherited as false.

```
// This defaults to Inherited = true. 
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    //...
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
public class YourAttribute : Attribute
{
    //...
}
```

Refer the below link for further reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56.aspx#cpconwritingcustomattributesanchor2